# if statement inserting 2 fields into db

Tags: php, mysqli

My question is too long winded to find an answer. Please excuse me. Maybe I just don't know how to abbreviate my question. Well here is the problem and and the question. See the code below:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $server = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'newsletter') or die("The Server Cannot Be Reached at this Time!");
        //$dbc = mysqli_select_db($server, 'newsletter') or die("There is a problem accessing the databse!");
        $query = mysqli_query($server, "INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES('$name','$email')");

        $name = strip_tags($name);
        $email = strip_tags($email);

        if(empty($name) || empty($email)) {
            echo "All Fields Must Be Filled In!";
        } else {
            echo "You have been successfully subscribed";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($server);
?>
```

This code works. It gets the information to the database when the user fills out the form. What I noticed is that when the user only fills in one field, i.e. name and leaves the email field empty the if statement returns the line ***"All Fields Must Be Filled In"***. Then you return to the page and fill in the email field and everything is fine. But when I check the database I notice that there is an insertion of an **id** and **name** for the attempt where the ***email*** was not filled out on the form. Is this normal? Or what am I doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are checking for `empty` after doing the insertion. Move the insertion code into else part

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $name = strip_tags($name);
    $email = strip_tags($email);

    if(empty($name) || empty($email)) {
        echo "All Fields Must Be Filled In!";
    } else {
        $server = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'newsletter') or die("The Server Cannot Be Reached at this Time!");
        //$dbc = mysqli_select_db($server, 'newsletter') or die("There is a problem accessing the databse!");
        $query = mysqli_query($server, "INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES('$name','$email')");
        mysqli_close($server);
        echo "You have been successfully subscribed";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to move the insert of the user into the success branch of the if statement:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];





$name = strip_tags($name);
$email = strip_tags($email);


if(empty($name) || empty($email)) {

        echo "All Fields Must Be Filled In!";


    } else {
        $server = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'newsletter') or die("The Server Cannot Be Reached at this Time!");
        //$dbc = mysqli_select_db($server, 'newsletter') or die("There is a problem accessing the databse!");

        $query = mysqli_query($server, "INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES('$name','$email')");
        mysqli_close($server);

        echo "You have been successfully subscribed";


            }



}




?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
if(empty($name) || empty($email))
```

into this

```
if(empty($name) && empty($email))
```

|| pipe sign mean OR in your condition you are telling that either name is empty or email is empty but in && and sign we are telling that either name is empty and email is empty return error.

```
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
```

Comment: No. "Or" is correct. If EITHER of them are empty, throw the error.

Comment: Then the database connection should be in else condition.

Comment: Definitely. The first condition displays an error and the else condition says you have been successfully created.

Answer (score 0):

following line should be written in else close

```
$query = mysqli_query($server, "INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES('$name','$email')");
```

and use

```
 if(empty($name) && empty($email))
```

not

```
if(empty($name) || empty($email))
```

Comment: No. "Or" is correct. If EITHER of them are empty, throw the error.

Comment: Them something will absolutely inserted null in database

Comment: Incorrect. Look at what the [empty()](http://php.net/empty) function does, and the code.

Comment: Just want to thank everybody for taking the time to sort this issue for me. There is a lot to digest here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should run the insert query in the else condition since here you are checking if a field is blank or not.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $name  = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $name  = strip_tags($name);
   $email = strip_tags($email);

   if(empty($name) || empty($email)) {
      echo "All Fields Must Be Filled In!";
   } else {
      $server = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'newsletter') or die("The Server Cannot Be Reached at this Time!");
      $query  = mysqli_query($server, "INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES('$name','$email')");
      mysqli_close($server);
      echo "You have been successfully subscribed";
   }
}

?>
```